# How to allow system_app set vendor_default_prop, or mtk_hal_camera (in vnd partition) get system_prop?

Tags: android, android-source, selinux

I tried to set a **persist** prop from a `system_app`, and get it from the `mtk_hal_camera` process. I tried 2 ways, neither worked:

1. `system_app` set `system_prop` OK, but `mtk_hal_camera` get `system_prop` FAILED:

> 09-30 15:04:09.248  7781  7781 W HwBinder:7781_2: type=1400
> audit(0.0:520169): avc: denied { read } for
> name="u:object_r:system_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=385
> scontext=u:r:mtk_hal_camera:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_prop:s0
> tclass=file permissive=0

the `system_prop` is like: `persist.sys.foo`;

I tried to add `allow mtk_hal_camera system_prop:file { read };`, in file:

> device/mediatek/sepolicy/custom/module/camera/non_plat/mtk_hal_camera.te

yet resulted in compile error:

> 2023-10-16 11:16:29 neverallow check failed at
> out_vnd_hal/target/product/mgvi_64_nfc_armv82/obj/ETC/plat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/plat_sepolicy.cil:22518
> from system/sepolicy/private/property.te:150 2023-10-16 11:16:29
> (neverallow base_typeattr_733 base_typeattr_743 (file (ioctl read
> write create setattr lock relabelfrom append unlink link rename open
> watch watch_mount watch_sb watch_with_perm watch_reads))) 2023-10-16
> 11:16:29  2023-10-16 11:16:29 allow at
> out_vnd_hal/target/product/mgvi_64_nfc_armv82/obj/ETC/vendor_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/vendor_sepolicy.cil:12983
> 2023-10-16 11:16:29 (allow mtk_hal_camera system_prop_31_0 (file
> (read)))

2. `mtk_hal_camera` get `vendor_default_prop` OK, but `system_app` set `vendor_default_prop` FAILED:

> 2023-10-01 19:45:35.156 1-1/? W//system/bin/init: type=1107
> audit(0.0:6250): uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:init:s0
> msg='avc: denied { set } for
> property=persist.vendor.camera.foo pid=13714
> uid=1000 gid=1000 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0
> tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=property_service
> permissive=0'

the `vendor_default_prop` is like: `persist.vendor.camera.foo`;

I tried to add `allow system_app vendor_default_prop:file { write };` in file:

> device/mediatek/sepolicy/custom/module/camera/non_plat/system_app.te

again, resulted in compile error:

> 2023-10-14 22:31:31 libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 507 of
> system/sepolicy/public/domain.te (or line 12716 of policy.conf)
> violated by allow system_app vendor_default_prop:file { write };
> 2023-10-14 22:31:32 libsepol.check_assertions: 1 neverallow failures
> occurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the macro system_public_prop or system_restricted_prop to define a new prop type. It will not break the neverallow rule.

```
# define a new prop type in property.te 
system_public_prop(mtk_camera_prop)

# label the prop in property_contexts
persist.vendor.camera.foo  u:object_r:mtk_camera_prop:s0 exact int

# allow system_app to set
set_prop(system_app, mtk_camera_prop)

# allow vendor to read
get_prop(mtk_hal_camera, mtk_camera_prop)
```